# How to Determine Sample Size for Generalized Linear Mixed Models?

Tags: probability, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, sample-size, binary-data

I want to design a cross-over study (clinical) to assess the performance of different treatments.

The response of the study is binary outcome: success or failure.

I have two fixed effects and one random effect in the model. I want to determine how many experimental units/participants do i need to have a reasonable statistical power while evaluating the design. Would 20 units be enough? How could I validate it?

I would appreciate very much for any input, reference, ...

Thank you.

Comment: Are 20 units supposed to be 20 total observations? If so, that is in my opinion dangerously low.

Comment: I assume that having a random effect means you have clustered dataset (e.g. several observations per participant), i.e. multilevel design. To determine sample size for a multilevel design, it is common to use simulations, meaning you generate mock data that resembles the data you intend to collect and then use a function such as powerSim from the simr package to estimate the power of your expected effect in a generated sample resembling the one you will try to collect. Here is a good tutorial for simr: https://humburg.github.io/Power-Analysis/simr_power_analysis.html.

Comment: An alternative is the MLPowerTool: http://www.hermanaguinis.com/crosslevel.html